# How can i detect if abc.exe is active/on top/using etc

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

With active i meant for example you are using browser now, so its active when you skip to another window, its not active anymore

How can i do it? im pretty new to vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and welcome to Stack Overflow - Sorry it took so long to get an answer!

You can use the Win32 API to call the `User32` `GetForegroundWindow` method... See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the API definition and [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetForegroundWindow.shtml) for a brief overview and link to some example usage.

[This](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_track_fg_window.html) is an example of an application which polls frequently to find the currently active window.

Incidentally, [this API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the window which has keyboard focus. 99% of the time, this will be the same as the above but there are some conceivable scenarios when the two will differ.

If you need further information, please ask